# How to store information in GAE's datastore

Tags: php, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to store information in the Google Cloud Datastore that is available in GAE.

I have JSON like the following:

```
{ "users": [
    "ABC123",
    "XYZ987",
    "ZHI663"
    ]
}
```

I am looking to store this in the data store but can't work out how. I can't use 'Text String' as it's limited to 500 characters and I need to be able to have many users.

I see in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) that there is a 'List' type which sounds exactly like what I need however this option does not show when I am creating an entity in the developers console. See image here:

[image: http://s27.postimg.org/v0x83n89f/entity.png]

If you can only use the 'List' type using the API can anyone show me an example of doing this in PHP?

Comment: You should mention that you are trying to create this entity manually using the Developers Console.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Are you saying the 'List' type is available in the API just not the developer console?

Comment: It's available in Java. I did not try in other languages, but I would imagine it's available there too.

Comment: GAE/PHP doesn't have native support for datastore yet. You could use https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE wont lets us modify complex things like `List` and `Text`.

Let me briefly explain,  `Text` or `List` or `Set` or `Map`.

> Text :  `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text`
>
> 1. We can store upto 20k characters for a text field.
> 2. It wont be indexed.
> 3. We cannot modify it in the datastore view.
>
> List or Set
>
> 1. We can store as many entries into it as we want.
> 2. Elements in this will result in complex index i.e. elements will form combination among themselves and hence GAE will index each
>      combination.
> 3. We can un-index it by having definition as un-index.
> 4. We cannot modify in  GAE datastore view.
>
> Map
>
> ```
> 1.Though GAE wont allow Map, we can serialize it and store as blob.   
> 2. Limited to 1MB   
> 3. We cannot view or modify it in the GAE datastore view.
> ```

Of the three, only `List or Set` is indexed. So if you want to make a query to check whether the json contains the user or not, you should use `List or Set.`

If you use other two, you need to fetch it, then check whether the user is there or not.

All three has its own advantages and disadvantages. So its up to you to decide which one you are going to use for your need.

If you want to use it while user logs in, then List or Set is the opt one as it can be easily queried because all the entries are pre indexed.

Comment: List or Set sounds like what I need. I need to be able to add a single user and retrieve the whole list of users. Am I able to add a single user to a List or Set without retrieving the List or Set first?

Comment: No. We cant modify them in directly.